# I lost % in html source when using stringWithContentsOfUrl

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

```
NSString *htmlSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:0x80000000 + kCFStringEncodingDOSKorean error:nil];
 NSLog(htmlSource);
```

I get html result tag like (col width="16"/)~~~ but the real html tag is (col width="16%"/)

% character disappears. what is problem?

Comment: why are you using `0x80000000` in the encoding argument?

Answer (score 1):

The string might still contain a `%`; `NSLog()` *itself* gives special significance to a `%` sign (consider what happens if you use `%@`, `%d`, etc.).

Try doing this: `NSLog(@"%@", htmlSource)`; that will log only an object (the string) and keep it out of the formatting argument.